# Add javascript to theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add the Nivo-slider code (not the WP plugin) to a theme. I've done it by adding this to the functions.php:

```
/* Add scripts for theme to work*/
function theme_add_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); //omit if jQuery already included
  wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider',  bloginfo('stylesheet_url') . '/wp-content/themes/pingst/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', 'jquery', '2.7.1');
  }
add_action('init', 'theme_add_scripts');
```

It seems like it should work but there are two problems.

1. When I manually added the script like this `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` inside the head tags, Nivo-slider did show up. Now it won't start. I know it finds the jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js because when I load it in the browser and look at the source the link to that js file is correct.
2. This adds this text `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/pingst` (well except it's the domain the site is placed on and not example.com) before the doctype and any thing else when looking at the source in the browser.

This is the complete output (got tired of change the domain-name to example.com, it's no secret anyway).

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/pingst<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="sv-SE">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title> Pingstförsamlingen Mörlunda</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="pingback" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/xmlrpc.php" />

  <!--   <script src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
  <meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Pingstförsamlingen Mörlunda &raquo; Hem kommentarsflöde" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?feed=rss2&#038;page_id=39" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gce_styles-css'  href='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/css/gce-style.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gce_custom_styles-css'  href='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/gr368o4ds072hbqilbmuaj1md8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/js/jquery-qtip.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var GoogleCalendarEvents = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/pingstwp.theninth.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","loading":"Loading..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/js/gce-script.js'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='prev' title='Bockara' href='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=33' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://pingstwp.theninth.se/' />

  <!-- Nivo-slider -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'sliceDown'
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Whole width -->
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/">
        <img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/logotype.png" alt="logotype" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Dropdown menu -->
    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="menu-huvudmeny" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=9">Barn</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=11">Församlingen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=26">Historia</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=31">Stöd församlingen</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=28">Kristen tro</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=33">Bockara</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=7">Ungdomar</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=5">Kalender</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/?page_id=2">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>    </div>

    <!-- Left sidebar -->

    <div id="sidebar">
            <!-- Frame no 1 -->
      <div class="frame-leftside">
<div class="cal-presentation">
<h2 class="widgettitle">Kalender</h2>
<p class="cal-eventname">&raquo; Smågrupp</p>
<p class="cal-date">Onsdag 2012-03-07 17:30</p><br />

<h3 class="cal-category">Barn</h3>

<p class="cal-eventname">&raquo; Söndagsskola</p>
<p class="cal-date">Söndag 2012-03-11 10:00</p><br />

<h3 class="cal-category">Ungdom</h3>
<p class="cal-eventname">&raquo; Tonår</p>
<p class="cal-date">Lördag 2012-03-10 17:00</p><br />

</div>
</div>
      <!-- Frame no 2 -->


      <!-- Frame no 3 -->

      <!-- Frame no 4 -->

      <!-- Frame no 5 (Post it) -->
      <div class="post-it"><h2 class="Post-it">Dagens bibelord</h2>         <div class="textwidget">Stilla din harm, låt din vrede slockna,
reta inte upp dig, det leder bara till ont.

Ps 37:8</div>
        </div>    </div>

    <!-- Main - This is right column with the real content -->

    <div id="main">
      <!-- Slideshow frame -->
      <div class="frame-fullsize">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
          <div class="ribbon"></div>
          <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/kyrkan.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/kyrkan3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/kyrkan4.jpg" alt="" />

            <img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/kyrkan2.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
    </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
          <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Content frame -->
      <div id="content-frame" class="frame-fullsize">

    <!-- Actual side content  -->
        <div id="content">
                                    <div class="post">
                <h2 class="blogtitle"><a href="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/">Hem</a></h2>

                  <div class="entry">
                    <p>Pingstförsamlingen i Mörlunda finns till för vanliga<br />
människor, som du och jag. Med våra förtjänster och våra<br />
dåliga sidor. Både ung, gammal och de som är någonstans mitt<br />
i mellan. Människorna som delar församlingsgemenskapen är på<br />
många sätt olika. Men det som förenar är tron på Jesus, inte<br />
bara som historisk person, utan framförallt levande<br />
idag. Jesus är den som ger människan ett liv med mål och<br />

mening.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Vi kan uppleva många saker i livet som meningsfullt;<br />
relationer, barn, barnbarn och så vidare. Men innerst inne<br />
längtar vi alla efter något mer. Vi brottas med frågan om<br />
den den yttersta meningen med tillvaron, om våra liv<br />
verkligen spelar roll och vad som händer efter<br />
döden. Predikaren säger om Gud att ”evigheten har han lagt i<br />
människornas hjärtan.” Vi kan vara så upptagna i livet med<br />

annat att vi inte hör frågorna från djupet av våra hjärtan,<br />
men likväl finns de där. I Jesus Kristus kan dessa frågor få<br />
ett svar.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Välkommen att vara med på en gudstjänst, cafékväll,<br />
tonår eller något annat som händer.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>I församlingen finns också människor som är beredda att<br />
samtala med dig som vill det. Det finns inga utbildade<br />
terapeuter, men medmänniskor som vill ta dig på allvar och<br />

är beredda att både lyssna på dig och dela sina egna<br />
erfarenheter om livet tillsammans med Jesus.</p>
                    <p class="postmetadata">
                                          </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
                          <div class="navigation">
                              </div>
                  </div>

        <!-- Right sidebar -->
        <div id="rightbar">

          <!-- Frame no 1 -->
          <div class="frame-rightside">         <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/akti.gif" class="iconbox-icon" alt=""/> 
<div class="iconbox-text">
<h2>Kalender</h2>
<a href="#">Vad händer i församlingen? &gt;&gt;</a>
</div></div>

        </div>
          <!-- Frame no 2 -->
          <div class="frame-rightside">         <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://pingstwp.theninth.se/wp-content/themes/pingst/images/fragetecken.gif" class="iconbox-icon" alt=""/> 
<div class="iconbox-text">
<h2>Frågor</h2>
<a href="#">Har du funderingar, kontakta oss här &gt;&gt;</a>
</div></div>
        </div>
          <!-- Frame no 3 -->


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Design: <a href="http://www.anxtreme.se">AnXtreme Foto &amp; Grafisk Produktion</a> | <a href="http://www.anxtreme.se">www.anxtreme.se</a> | <a href="http://www.andersholm.se">www.andersholm.se</a>

    </div>
  </div></body>
</html>
```

## Edit 1:

The first lines of header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title><?php wp_title(); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

  <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: what are the first 2-3 lines of header.php in your theme? Currently your site outputs the style.css file before the doctype. fixing this will probably the first problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you use '[bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)' which will echo what it is getting.
Use '[get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)' to make wp return instead of echo.

So change that in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider',  bloginfo('stylesheet_url') . '/wp-content/themes/pingst/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', 'jquery', '2.7.1');
```

should be

```
wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider',  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', 'jquery', '2.7.1');
```

That should fix problem nr 2 and hopefully also problem nr 1